# Class number of the cyclotomic tower

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, galois-theory, diophantine-equations, galois-representations

Let ${\Bbb Q}(\zeta_{\infty})$ be the field obtained by adjoining all roots of unity. We define

Cl(${\Bbb Q}(\zeta_{\infty})$)$\colon= \underset{m > 1}{\varinjlim}~{\mathrm{Cl}}({\Bbb Z}[\zeta_m])$.

Q. Does the following isomorphism hold for an arbitrary integer n > 0? :

### \begin{equation*}
Cl({\Bbb Q}(\zeta_{\infty}))/n \cong {\Bbb Z}/n{\Bbb Z} \cdots (\sharp).
\end{equation*}

This is the analogue of function fields over ${\Bbb F}_p$. That is, if we adjoin all roots of unity to a function field $k(C)$, it has a unique model of projective smooth curve $\overline{C}$ over $\overline{\Bbb F}_p$. Hence, we have the following isomorphism$\colon$

\begin{equation*}
{\mathrm{Pic}}(\overline{C})/n \cong {\Bbb Z}/n{\Bbb Z} \cdots(\dagger).
\end{equation*}

My guess is whether $(\sharp)$ also holds like $({\dagger})$.

Pierre Matsumi

Comment: The field you are considering is somehow immense. There are clear answers in case you consider the field $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{p^\infty})$ for some fixed $p$, but the general case is quite intricate. Why would you expect this copy of $\mathbb{Z}$ to show up?

Comment: Can you be more precise about the maps you mean in your direct limit? You are taking a direct limit of finite groups, it seems, so this must surely be a torsion group and in particular there is no chance of a copy of Z showing up.

Comment: The title says "class number", but the question appears to be about class groups, not numbers. Please edit/clarify.

Comment: The question how to translate knowledge on the Picard group of curves $C$ and their zeta-functions over to number field is the basic question of Iwasawa theory. The analogy can not be as good as you hope for. I would expect your limit to be rather larger. You are using that $\operatorname{Pic}^0(\bar C)$ is $n$-divisible.